# Auto focus input when dialog open in vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

i have a dialog which contain input text using v-menu, and it will appear when hit a button, how to focus input text when dialog is open. I try $ref bat it not work

```
newFolderClick(){
  this.$refs["input_new_folder"].focus();
  //it still undefined
}
```

```
<input @keyup.enter="confirmCreateFolder" v-debounce:100ms="checkValidate" v-model="newFolderName" class="storage-dialog-input" ref="input_new_folder"/>
```

Comment: You need to call `newFolderClick` basis on the same value when dialog appears.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to use `$nextTick`

Like so:

```
newFolderClick(){
  this.$refs["input_new_folder"].focus();
}

created () {
    this.$nextTick(() => this.newFolderClick());
}
```